# How to apply Prefixfree.js to only a particular Div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prefixfree

I have applied [Prefixfree.js](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/) to my website but all the icons/images repeats (background-repeat). I want to apply [**Prefixfree.js**](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/) to only a particular Div to resolve this issue. How can i accomplish this?

Is there a way to apply, in jQuery, the Prefixfree.js for a #div only? for example something like this:

```
$('#myDiv').append('(function()... /*Prefixfree code*/...documentElement);');
```

or

```
Prefixfree.applyTo('#myDiv');
```

Thank you!

Comment: Probably something is wrong with your CSS not prefixfree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prefixfree scans all included stylesheets and style tags for properties that would need a predfix and applies them. The only way (I know) is to set `data-noprefix` on those elements (link, style) and use an extra style-tag or stylesheet that'll be prefixed.
Seems hacky to me.